# Place dynamic view between two views vertically

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Here is the problem: I want to place a view with dynamic height which will be calculated at runtime according to the width (lets call it center view) between two views. The tricky part is that the top and bottom views should adapt their height to fit the space left after center view measurement and layout, and their height shouldn't be less that minHeight. I managed to put all three views in vertical linear layout, where top and bottom have weight = 1 and center view is some fixed height, but when the center view height is becomes bigger than some value it covers top and bottom views and their minHeight param is ignored. Here is the part of the layout, hope it helps:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="84dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- some content here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="62dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- some content here -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the middle view to have a height that is calculated from the width, but limited to the total height minus the minimum heights of the top and bottom views? If that's wrong, what gives when the total height available is less than center_height + 2*minHeight?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, I know that it can be adjusted at runtime according to the top and bottom views height, but this solution is far frome elegant

Comment: Interesting set of constraints. I'm not sure you can do this with a `LinearLayout`; you may need to define your own layout class (maybe by subclassing `LinearLayout`).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by restricting height of the center view to windowHeight - (minHeight1 + minHeight2) as minHeight1 and minHeight2 are known constants. If the height is less than windowHeight - (minHeight1 + minHeight2) the linear layout does fine